# Fastest way to read and batch images from AWS S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, file-io

I'm wondering if there's a function similar to [tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory)
 that can read images from a folder in AWS S3 and returns them as batches (as numpy arrays, tf Dataset etc.) in Python for preprocessing / training in Sagemaker. Solutions I found thus far involves writing a custom function / for loop to read the images one at a time and batching them manually; I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: How did it go? Still unclear why you can't do that?

Comment: @Marcin I'm still working on this, unfortunately s3fs-fuse seems to not support Windows.  I'm currently saving all the S3 image path as a tf dataset, then applying `.map` with a read image method and utilizing the `num_parallel_calls`. However, this is only slightly faster than a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you could try using [s3fs-fuse](https://github.com/s3fs-fuse/s3fs-fuse) to mount your S3 bucket as a local folder on your workstation. This will make a pretend folder on your local computer corresponding to your S3. This way, your function may be tricked to treating the S3 as a regular folder.